# Blender Python Advanced Panel in 3d Space

Tags: python, interface, panel

Have you got any ideas on how to achieve this kind of interface that pops up at the 3d space?
This image is from the archipack addon.
[image: Blender Archipack Panel]
[image]
I've read the script and the panel itself is found on the 3d space UI and wondering how he created this type of panel with layout design and interactive buttons inside the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the interface yourself in a modal operator. See the modal operator template in the text editor, and use the [bgl](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bgl.html) module to do the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Archipack's sample may be overkill, as it does override regular preset_loader operator and hide bgl logic behind an abstraction layer.
[archipack_presets.py](https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/blob/master/archipack_preset.py) and [archipack_gl.py](https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/blob/master/archipack_gl.py)

You may take a look at asset flinger implementation.
[Asset flinger github repo](https://github.com/BlenderAid/Asset-Flinger)

As a side note, bgl module is currently not supported in 2.8 series and a complete rewrite is planed, so this api is likely to change.